# Как передать внутрь функции саму кнопку

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Функция

```
System::Void buttonPressed(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{

}
```

В цикле создания кнопок

```
playGroundPart[i, j]->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::buttonPressed);
```

Как можно сделать, чтобы на нажатие этой кнопки передавалась сама кнопка в эту функцию и затем можно было взять из неё значение(Text) и сделать неактивной.

Answer (score 1):

```
System::Void buttonPressed(System::Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
        {
            Button^ button = (Button^)sender;
            MessageBox::Show(button->Text); //вывод текста с кнопки
        }
```